# Make tile-ID request URL work with mapbox-style "satellite-streets" using folium

Tags: mapbox, tiles, folium, satellite-image

I use `Python` for plotting geospatial data on maps.
For certain map-styles, such as `["basic", "streets", "outdoors", "light", "dark", "satellite", "satellite-streets"]`, I need a mapbox-access token and for some *geospatial plotting packages* like `folium` I even need to create my own link for retrieving the map-tiles.

So far, it worked great with the style `"satellite"`:

```
mapbox_style = "satellite"
mapbox_access_token = "....blabla"

request_link = f"https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.{mapbox_style}/{{z}}/{{x}}/{{y}}@2x.jpg90?access_token={mapbox_access_token}"
```

However, when choosing `"satellite-streets"` as mapbox-tile-ID, the output doesn't show a background map anymore. It fails with inserting `"satellite-streets", "satellitestreets" and "satellite_streets"` into the aforementioned link-string.

Why is that and how can I come to know what's the correct tile-ID-name for `"satellite-streets"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer when reaching out to the customer support.
Apparently, one has to access the static APIs which have specific names listed on their website:

> "In general, the styles that you mentioned including
>   "satellite_streets"  that you are referencing are our classic styles
>   that are going to be deprecated starting June 1st. I would recommend
>   using our modern static API the [equivalent modern styles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles). This
>   will allow you to see the most updated street data as well.
>
> **Like the example request below:**
>
> https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11/tiles/1/1/0?access_token={your_token}
>
> [Here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/#determine-if-a-tileset-id-is-associated-with-a-classic-style) is more info on the deprecation of the classic styles and
>   the migration guide for them."

**My personal adaptation after having tried everything out myself, is:**

Via combining the above-mentioned with the details on how to construct a Mapbox-request link on [this documention from mapbox' website](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles),
I finally managed to make it work.

*An example request looks like so (in python using f-strings):*

```
mapbox_tile_URL = f"https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{tileset_ID_str}/tiles/{tilesize_pixels}/{{z}}/{{x}}/{{y}}@2x?access_token={mapbox_access_token}"
```

The tileset_ID_str could be e.g. `"satellite-streets-v11"` which can be seen at the following [link containing valid static maps](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles).

Comment: Helpful info - can't believe this isn't documented clearly on the MapBox site. It's also unfortunate that the pricing of the static maps API is astronomical when used as a substitute for tile requests :(